# Custom loss function Tensorflow 2 [Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, mse

I'm trying to use custom loss function and started with simple MSE. Do not pay attention to `oscillator` function, it needs just for creating data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf


def oscillator(d_, w0_, x):
    assert d_ < w0_
    w = np.sqrt(w0_**2 - d_**2)
    phi = np.arctan(-d_/w)
    A = 1/(2*np.cos(phi))
    cos = np.cos(phi+w*x)
    sin = np.sin(phi+w*x)
    exp = np.exp(-d_*x)
    return exp*2*A*cos



# PARAMETERS:
np.random.seed(5)
N = 20
epochs = 2000
d, w0 = 2, 20
nn_dim = 64


# DATA:
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = oscillator(d,w0,x)

x_train = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0,0.35,N)[:,np.newaxis], axis=0)
y_train = oscillator(d,w0,x_train)

tf_y = tf.Variable(y_train,dtype=tf.float32)



# LAYERS:
input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
Layer_1 = Dense(nn_dim, activation="tanh")(input_layer)
Layer_2 = Dense(nn_dim, activation="tanh")(Layer_1)
output_layer = Dense(1)(Layer_2)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)



loss_func = tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.squared_difference(tf_y,output_layer))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_func, metrics=['mse'])


md = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=epochs,verbose=1)
y_pred = model.predict(x[:,np.newaxis])


# PLOTTING:
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(md.history['loss'], label='training')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,label="Exact solution")
plt.scatter(x_train,y_train,label="Data",color="orange")
plt.plot(x,y_pred,label="Prediction",linestyle="--",color="red")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The code above produces the following error:
**TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly.
Process finished with exit code 1**

The problem is in `loss_func = tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.squared_difference(tf_y,output_layer))`. I think this is because of different dimensions of `tf_y` and `output_layer`.
Any ideas how to compute MSE by hand using `output_layer` and `y`?

Comment: Do tf_y and output_layer have the same type?

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never seen a loss defined like that (and I hardly think that it might work), you usually want to create a function:

```
def loss_func(tf_y, output_layer):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.squared_difference(tf_y,output_layer))
```

from the documentation:

> **loss argument of compile**: may be a string (name of loss function), or a tf.keras.losses.Loss instance. See tf.keras.losses. A loss function is any callable with the signature loss = fn(y_true,y_pred), where y_true are the ground truth values, and y_pred are the model's predictions

Comment: Ok, thanks! I found my problem and your answer solved it.